# When adding a new dynamic row with partial views, all rows cleared after deleting one

Tags: asp.net-core

When the user adds an item to a list everything works fine until you delete an entry. The row gets deleted but once you add a new row, all rows are deleted with the new row added. The issue is that once you delete a row and add a new one it loads from the database, if you haven't saved the order yet everything entered is lost.

Is there a way to delete, then add, without saving the order every time you delete an item?

> Js delete function

```
function del(e, id) {
e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
if (id === 0) {
    var row = $(this).closest(".tablerow0");
    row.remove();
} else {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Business/Order/DeleteOrderItem',
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
}
}
```

> HTML

```
     <div id="orderItemsContainer" style="width: 100%;float: left;">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)
     </div>
```

> Add Item

```
//Add new item
$(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', 'click', function (e) {
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    data: $('#forming').serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Business/Order/AddOrderItem',
    success: function (partialView) {
        console.log("partialView: " + partialView);
        $('#orderItemsContainer').html(partialView);
    }
  });
});
```

> Html delete button

```
    <button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btntext-danger font-weight-bold clear-item" title="Remove" asp-action="DeleteOrderItem" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-area="Business"
 onClick="$(this).closest('.tablerow0').remove(); Update(); del(event, @Model.Id);showHideBtn()">
```

> Controller

```
    public IActionResult DeleteOrderItem(int id, [Bind("Items")] Order order)
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            return PartialView("Item", order);
        }
        var itemToDelete = _db.Items.Find(id);
        _db.Remove(itemToDelete);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(itemToDelete);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddOrderItem([Bind("Items")] Order order)
    {
        order.Items.Add(new Item());
        return PartialView("Item", order);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public IActionResult DeleteOrderItem(int id, [Bind("Items")] Order order)
> {
>     if (id == 0)
>     {
>         return PartialView("Item", order);
>     }
>     var itemToDelete = _db.Items.Find(id);
>     _db.Remove(itemToDelete);
>     _db.SaveChanges();
>     return Json(itemToDelete);
> }
>
> [HttpPost]
> [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
> public async Task<ActionResult> AddOrderItem([Bind("Items")] Order order)
> {
>     order.Items.Add(new Item());
>     return PartialView("Item", order);
> }
> ```

Check the above code, when add items, the items are not inserted into the database, but when you delete items, it will delete items from the database. So, the issue might relate that.

You could refer the comment to modify your code:

```
public IActionResult DeleteOrderItem(int id, [Bind("Items")] Order order)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return PartialView("Item", order);
    }
    //1. delete items from database.
    var itemToDelete = _db.Items.Find(id);
    _db.Remove(itemToDelete);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    //2. query database get the latest items:
    
    var result = _db.Items.ToList();

    //then return the items to the main page and display them
    return Json(result);
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddOrderItem([Bind("Items")] Order order)
{
    //1. insert the items into database.
     
    //2. query the database, get the latest items.
   
    //3. add a new Item instance, to let use enter the new value.
    order.Items.Add(new Item());      
    return PartialView("Item", order);
}
```

Comment: Since it loads from the database after you delete then add, is there a way to keep the list without saving everytime you delete?

Comment: @robert_rg, do you mean you don't want to save the data into the database every time.  If that is the case, you could consider [using session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state) to store the list (need to add SessionExtensions), when add or remove items, you could get the list from the session, then add/remove item from the list, after that reset the session (let the session store the latest data). Then, when you want to save data into database, get the data from session and insert them into the database.